# React Loading in Stylesheet only when Component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have an `App` Component that does all my routing for my project, where I import all the necessary components.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import Login from "../../login/Login";
import Overview from "../../overview/Overview";
import SubNav from "../../subnav/SubNav";
import ForgotPassword from "../../forgot-password/ForgotPassword";

const App = () => {

   return (
      <div className="App">
         <Router>
            <div className="App-container">
            <Switch>
               <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact />
               <Route path="/forgotpassword" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
               <Route path={"/"} component={SubNav} />
            </Switch>
               <Route exact path={"/"} component={Overview} />
               <Route path={"/overview"} component={() => <Overview />} />
            </div>
         </Router>
      </div>
   );

}

export default App;
```

For example, in my `Login` component, I have the following imports...

```
import React from 'react';
import './Login.scss';
import LoginBenefits from './LoginBenefits';
import LoginFormContainer from './LoginFormContainer';
```

The issue I am having here with the import of the `Login.scss`

In this file I do imports of specific other scss files that are related to the `Login` Component. Say, for example, I had one that styled a class called `.Tabs`

```
@import "../../scss/_variables";

$Tabs-padding: 15px;

@import "../tabs/Tabs.scss";

.Login {....
```

Now for example, if in the `ForgotPassword` Component, if I were to add a div with a `className` of `Tabs` it would then style it correctly. This isn't what I want, it means that whatever is imported in the `Login` component gets loaded throughout the whole project, which means I cannot override any SASS variables without having to import the same SASS file again and makes the webpack bundled css file larger than it needs to be.

I guess my question is, how do I contain the `Login.scss` to only import when the `Login` component actually renders?

Or am I going about the whole imports in the wrong way?

Comment: You need dynamic imports and code splitting

Comment: @UjinT34 Are there any good docs/tutorials on that for SASS?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/ and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy

Answer (score 1):

What you have to understand is, when you import your scss files. They get converted to css and are rendered as 'internal styles' in the app. Basically they become global css rendered in the header. So unless you use scss properly and structure your css with a hierarchy you cannot achieve containment!

> But what you have stumbled upon is an intriguing idea, which has
>   pushed the community to come up with a solution called **css in js**!

Look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js9BihmW9ak)!

The basic idea is to bring css into the React Component **containing the styles inside the component**. It is achieved using using template strings. This is groundbreaking because you now how the full power of javascript behind you to manipulate css!

[This](https://github.com/MicheleBertoli/css-in-js) is an exhaustive list of frameworks that can help you with this. [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) is the most widely adopted framework. But you can take a pick!

This is an example of how your code will look

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
`;

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
  &:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 480px) {
    width: 160px;
  }
`;

const App = () => (
  <Container>
    <Button>Click me!</Button>
  </Container>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

And styled components takes care of containing  your css to the relevant component!

Answer (score 0):

You need to bundle the all your scss file into single file. You can do this in webpack config file with use of ExtractTextPlugin

```
 module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "dist/assets/css/style.bundle.css"
    })
  ]
```

Comment: Is this what I want? If it imports all into one file, isn't this the root of my problem, that all my css gets imported in all components and not just `Login` styling in `Login`, it's `Login` styling in `Login` and `ForgotPassword` etc.

Comment: so have implemented the code-splitting into your code